# How to add the value of two variables together

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have two variables and I want to add there values together, the variables munt be added like math because the variables are DF = ("374") AND DG = (INPUTLENGTH)… can I do it like this...

MyVariable = MyVariable + MyOtherVariable

Answer (score 2):

```
variable = int(df) + dg
```

You have to convert df, a string, to an integer, so it can be added to the other integer.

Comment: it just says Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\test.py", line 25, in <module>
    variable = int(b) + a
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Try converted them both to ints

Comment: Can you assist me on how to do that

Comment: int(a) + int(b)